# Apparent variable 'serviceName' was found in a static scope... when trying to access services from a static method in a non-artefact groovy file

Tags: spring, grails

In a Grails 3 app I am using Spring Beans to inject two services into a non-artefact Groovy file located at `src/main/groovy/demo/Menu.groovy`. Then from a controller I try to call a create Menu static method but I have errors when from the static method is called methods of injected services

The Menu class looks like this

```
package demo

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import demo.CategoryService
import demo.ItemService

class Menu {

    @Autowired
    CategoryService categoryService

    @Autowired
    ItemService itemService

    List<Category> categoryList
    List<Item> itemList

    public static final Menu create(final String categoryName) {
        List<Category> categoryList = categoryService.listByEnabled(true)

        new Menu (
            categoryList: categoryList,
            itemList: itemService.listByCategoryName(categoryName ?: categoryList[0].name)
        )
    }
}
```

CategoryService and ItemService are both [GORM Data Services](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#dataServices) and are injected using Spring bean in resource.groovy file

```
beans = {    
    menu(demo.Menu)
}
```

From the controller action when i call the create Menu static method

```
class MenuController {

    def menu(final String categoryName) {
        respond Menu.create(categoryName)
    }
}
```

I get the following errors:

```
/home/desktop/pos/src/main/groovy/demo/Menu.groovy: 17: Apparent variable 'categoryService' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'categoryService' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 17, column 39.
           List<Category> categoryList = categoryService.listByEnabled(true)
```

And the same for itemService

```
/home/desktop/pos/src/main/groovy/demo/Menu.groovy: 21: Apparent variable 'itemService' was found in a static scope but doesn't refer to a local variable, static field or class. Possible causes:
You attempted to reference a variable in the binding or an instance variable from a static context.
You misspelled a classname or statically imported field. Please check the spelling.
You attempted to use a method 'itemService' but left out brackets in a place not allowed by the grammar.
 @ line 21, column 23.
               itemList: itemService.listByCategoryName(categoryName ?: categoryList[0].name)
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is happening because you've defined `categoryService` as an instance field (no `static` modifier), which you can't access from a `static` method.

Since you're already creating a `Menu` bean, just try injecting it instead of making the `create` method `static`:

```
class MenuController {

    def menu // Grails should inject it by bean name here

    def menu(final String categoryName) {
        respond menu.create(categoryName)
    }
}
```

Then remove `static` from the declaration:

```
public final Menu create(final String categoryName) {
```

This does beg the question though, why not make `Menu` a bonified Grails service? E.g. move it to grails-app/services and let Grails manage creating and injecting the other services?

Comment: Thanks Bryan. For the clarification and the recommendation.